# ActiveRecord - Search by nested has_many :through

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I am creating a location-based application that lists reading programs on a map. Each program has many age_groups (through program_age_groups) and has many locations (through program_locations). For the search results, I need to list each program_location matching the user's criteria. I created a search model, which also has many age_groups through search_age_groups. My question is, how do I filter the program locations based on its associated programs' age_group_ids? I can get it to work by doing something like this in the search model:

```
program_locations = ProgramLocation.all.includes(program: :age_groups)
program_locations = program_locations.where(age_groups: self.age_group_ids)
```

However, this creates a join statement on age_group_ids, and when I loop through the program locations and list the program's details, only the age groups matching the search age groups show up. Even if the program has other age groups, they will only show up if the user selects those in the search, or if the age groups field is blank on the search.

**EDIT: Clarification**

For example, say Program 1 has age_groups 0-2 and 3-5, and Program 2 has age_group 6-10. A user does a search and selects only age_group 0-2. When I display the results, it will correctly filter out Program 2, but it will display:

Program 1
Age Groups: 0-2

when it should display

Program 1
Age Groups: 0-2, 3-5

Any ideas?  This seems like a common problem, and I've run into something similar in the past, but I can't seem to find a straight-forward solution. I tried using reject, but that does not return an activerecord relation, and I need to add a pagination call at the end of the query.

Comment: You are asking for a search feature why would you expect results outside of the search parameters? Question seems unclear to me when you say "only the age groups matching the search age groups show up" isn't that the expected output from a search?

Comment: I want to filter the programs based on the search age groups, but when I display each matching program on the results page, it should show all of that program's age groups. I can get around this by reloading the program before displaying it, but that results in extra database queries (one for each program displayed).

Comment: So you are looking for a `ActiveRecord::Realtion` Object of `Program`s or `Program_Location`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could scope them like so:

```
class Program
   has_many :program_age_groups
   has_many :age_groups, through: :program_age_groups
   has_many :program_locations
   has_many :locations, through: :program_locations

   scope :by_age_group,->(age_group){ 
                          program_ids = program_age_groups.where(age_group: age_group).pluck(:program_id)
                          where(id: program_ids)
                         }
   scope :by_location,->(location){
                          program_ids = program_locations.where(location: location).pluck(:program_id)
                          where(id: program_ids)
                          }

end
```

Then call with

```
age_groups = ['0-2']
Program.by_age_group(age_groups)
```

This will return an `ActiveRecord::Relation[]` of `Program`s with the specified age groups.
Or

```
location = "Some location"
age_groups = ['0-2']
Program.by_location(location).by_age_group(age_groups)
```

`scopes` are a very powerful tool and I find them especially useful for searching as you can chain them together nicely while preserving readability.

**Update**

```
class ProgramLocation
    belongs_to :program
    belongs_to :location

    scope :by_age_group,->(age_group){
          program_ids = Program.by_age_group(age_group).pluck(:id)
          where(program_id: program_ids)
         }
    scope :by_location,->(location){
          location_ids = Location.where(name: location).pluck(:id)
          where(location_id: location_ids
          }

end
```

This assumes that your location as an attribute `name` that you are searching for in the scope not sure if this is true but should get you somewhere close.

Comment: Thanks, this looks close to what I'll need. However, I'm trying to get an ActiveRecord::Relation of ProgramLocation objects. I think this is where I'm struggling.

Comment: @dvanderb You might want to appropriately scope `ProgramLocation` then. But you should be able to use the above scopes as such `program_locations = Program.by_age_group(age_group).program_locations`

Comment: Can you help out on how I'd scope ProgramLocation? That's what I'm struggling with. I don't think ```program_locations = Program.by_age_group(age_group).program_locations``` works

Comment: @dvanderb Sorry you are correct that will not work you could `flat_map` them but you want an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object so let me see what I can do

Comment: Thank you very much, this pretty much worked. Just for everyone's references, I had to tweak one scope slightly. in program.rb, the scope couldn't use the program_age_groups association since this was not being called on a program instance. Instead, the scope I used became ```scope :by_age_group,->(age_group){ program_ids = ProgramAgeGroup.where(age_group: age_group).pluck(:program_id)
                          where(id: program_ids)
                         }```